# http 045: method not allowed error while loading data to hadoop cluster using knox gateway-0.3.0

Tags: hadoop, curl, knox-amazon-s3-client

I am trying to list data present in hadoop cluster and also copy the data using curl command
but i am getting http 405 error.
Below is the command i am using.

```
curl -iku guest:guest-password  -L -T samples/hadoop-examples.jar \
-X PUT  "https://{172.17.198.172}:8443\
/gateway/sandbox/webhdfs/v1/user/guest/knox-sample/lib/hadoop-examples.jar?op=CREATE
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this using the following curl command and had success:

```
curl -i -v -k -u guest:guest-password -L -T /Users/larry/hadoop-examples.jar -X PUT "https://{localhost}:8443/gateway/sandbox/webhdfs/v1/user/guest/knox-sample/lib/hadoop-examples.jar?op=CREATE"
```

It resulted in the expected HTTP 100 continue, 307 for the redirect and PUT and 201 created.

A subsequent curl command listed the contents of the target directory successfully listing the file as present:

```
curl -i -v -k -u guest:guest-password https://localhost:8443/gateway/sandbox/webhdfs/v1/user/guest/knox-sample/lib?op=LISTSTATUS
```

There are a couple things in curl command that you posed that are a bit odd:

- The backslash continuation characters seem to be left over maybe from copying examples from somewhere they are not needed
- You didn't complete the quotes around the URL
- the {} brackets around the host ip in the URL is probably also left over from a variable in an example that you copied - I don't think that they are hurting anything as I tried it with that and it worked.

I suspect that some combination of the above issues caused the URL to be truncated or something in which a PUT was inappropriate for the received URL and/or operation parameter.

I hope this is helpful for you.

If the [user guide](http://knox.apache.org/books/knox-0-4-0/knox-0-4-0.html#WebHDFS) isn't clear about this then we would love for you to file a [jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KNOX-362?jql=project%20%3D%20KNOX) and we'll get that resolved.